# jQuery UI Draggable and Droppable, reverting and accepting elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have been experimenting with this code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/vm9DS/) It highlights and let you know which boxes you can drop the boxes onto but it is not accepting any droppables. Does anyone know how I can alter this code to accept a droppable instead of it just reverting back?

```
$(".DragItem").draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone" 
});

$(".DropItem").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    over: function (event, ui) {
        var dropItem = $(this);
        var dragItem = $(ui.draggable);
        var valid = String(dropItem.data("id")).indexOf(dragItem.data("id")) > -1;
        if (valid) {
            dropItem.addClass("DropTargetValid");
        } else {
            dropItem.addClass("DropTargetInvalid");
        }
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        var dropItem = $(this);
        dropItem.removeClass("DropTargetValid");
        dropItem.removeClass("DropTargetInvalid");
    },
    deactivate: function (event, ui) {
        var dropItem = $(this);
        dropItem.removeClass("DropTargetValid");
        dropItem.removeClass("DropTargetInvalid");
    } 
});
```

Comment: where do you define what happens on a drop?

Comment: I think we're missing some code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to append the clones() to the correct divs and revert them if they don't match, first `accept:` all the dragable elements and then handle the revert in the `drop:` section.
also you will need to create and save the origin position for the ellement you clone and drag so you can revert him to its original position and then removing it from the page.

Here is the finall script demo:

[**JSnippet demo draggable & droppable**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/321/jQuery-UI-draggable-and-droppable)

have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I would start from something like this:

- re-use the built-in query-ui functionality, e.g. "[accept](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept)" or "[activeClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-activeClass)" parameters of a droppable
- if there is a small number of containers - you might declare "droppables" separately and use "accept" to e.g. allow only certain classes of draggables (like in the demo below)
- trying to "hack" draggables & droppables is possible but not very easy, especially with complex elements (if draggables and droppables have more complex html structure than just flat divs)

**Sample**:

```
$(".drop1").droppable({
    accept: '.drag1',
    activeClass: 'DropTargetValid',
    drop: function (ev, ui) {
        $(ev.target).append(ui.draggable.clone());
    }
});
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/13/)

**--- EDIT ---**

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vm9DS/14/)

Comment: I have used accept already and the problem is that all the boxes accept all of the draggables because the class is the same for all but the only thing that separates the draggables is an unique id number and i dont know how to use that so that all of the draggables wont be accepted in all of the droppables.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  tborychowski your demo works fine but I still wanted the boxes that arent droppable to still highlight in red and your demo is not doing that.